# compiled dart code not running in IE 10 and IE 11

Tags: dart, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, dart2js

I am having trouble with a small dart app which runs perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox and... guess what.... not in IE 10 and 11 (Project Spartan in Win10 Preview works!).

It is a simple UI controll logic like so:

```
...
//init elements
SelectElement studyList = querySelector('#studies');
SelectElement roleList = querySelector('#roles');
SelectElement siteList = querySelector('#sites');
ButtonElement createButton = querySelector('#create');

//Kick in the UI logic
_populateStudies();

//UI logic
_populateStudies() {
  for (var study in studies) {
    OptionElement option = new OptionElement();
    option.text = study;
    studyList.children.add(option);
  }
  for (OptionElement element in studyList.children) {
    throw new Exception("ADDING_HANDLER");
```

**//the following is executed, handler seems to get attached**

```
    element.onClick.listen(_studyClickHandler);
  }
}
```

**//Never executed in IE from here on**

```
_studyClickHandler(Event e) {
  siteList.children.clear();
  roleList.children.clear();
  _populateRoles();
}

_populateRoles(){
  List<String> roles = context.getRolesFor(studyList.selectedOptions[0].text);
  for (var role in roles) {
    OptionElement option = new OptionElement();
    option.text = role;
    roleList.children.add(option);
  }
  for (OptionElement element in roleList.children) {
    element.onClick.listen(_roleClickHandler);
  }
}
...
```

In IE the second selection box stays empty.
Chrome and Firefox handle the code as expected, populating the box's children according to the element selected in the first selection box.
I have no idea what the problem is... I refactored the handlers to be anonymous functions

```
onClick.listen((_){
  handle stuff
});
```

Console shows no errors at all.
Maybe there is an easy solution for it but I am relatively new to dart and can't figure it out?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please add a code example with all code that we can run in the browser.

Comment: It depends on data fetched by AJAX calls. I will try to mock it a bit and post a woprking piece of code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the `click` handler registration is not supported on `<option>` in the browsers you mention. Alternatively you can register your callback on the `SelectElement.onChange` and retrieve the selected with something like :

```dart
import 'dart:html';
void main() {
  SelectElement select = querySelector('select');
  select.onChange.listen((_) {
    final opt = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    print(opt.value);
  });
}
```

You can [try it on DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/0b9bc3e3d52005c92b36) with those browsers.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved my issue. One more question: Is it me or IE not following the conventions in this case ? ;-)